How can I log only put requests to AWS Kinesis that failed after the last retry?
I have one AWS Kinesis data stream shard that allows up to 1000 records / second. My applications (plural) are way below that on average. However, certain bursts can happen that go up to 4000 records / second being sent (only for one second, maybe two).
As written, these requests come from several applications. That's why I thought the best approach would be to configure the client to automatically retry on error. I use AWS SDK v1.
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig();
clientConfiguration.setRetryMode(RetryMode.STANDARD);

This should retry up to three times with pauses in between. I have no idea how long these pauses are but as far as I understood, each pause is longer than the previous one.
In addition I also passed an AsyncHandler to the putRecordAsync method. This handler logs the error on it onError method.
What I don't like about it, is, that this method is also called when the first attempt failed with a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException. I'd like to log requests only if the last attempt failed, so that I know that data is actually missing and was not sent.
How can I achieve this?
What other approach could be used to ensure that all requests reach the data stream assuming that on average (< 1m) I'm below the 1000 records / second?

Amazon's SDK's API supports receiving a RetryPolicy
You can do something like:
var retries = 3;
var retryPolicy = RetryPolicy.builder()
  .numRetries(retries)
  .retryCondition((context -> {
    if (context.retriesAttempted() < 3) {
      return true;
    }
    var record = context.originalRequest().getValueForField("record", Record.class).orElse(null);
    log.error("Failed sending record: `{}`", record);
    return false;
  }))
  .build();

var clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
  .retryPolicy(retryPolicy)
  .build();
KinesisClient.builder()
  .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
  .build();


Unfortunately this is a solution for SDK v2. I use the first one. The main problem is, that com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicyAdapter#shouldRetry is called which first checks if max retries have been reached and only if not calls the shouldRetry method of the RetryCondition. So I never know whether the last attempt was succesfull.
